# Does make any sense using cleanup code after an infinite loop?

Tags: c, linux

I'm reading code for a linux daemon and its main() function is structured like this:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv){
  
    // code which spawns some worker threads, sets up some
    // signal handlers for clean termination, etc.
    // ...

   for(;;){ sleep(1); }

   p_clean_exit();

   return 0;
}
```

As it stands this makes no sense to me.
The for loop will keep the process alive, waking every sencond, then going back to sleep.
p_clean_exit() wil never be called nor 0 will be returned from the last statement.

Of course there's code elsewhere which sends signals, and and installed handlers which in turn call p-clen_exit() on their own for program termination. But this one instance here will never be reached. Right?

Does this make actual sense under some circumstance?

Comment: I do not see any reason for this code. I concur with your analysis here, this code seems to be useless.

Comment: It is worth leaving in, so that if in the future the code is modified you already have what is needed without having to trawl through archived versions.

Comment: In a large project, code that passes [static analysis](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tools_for_static_code_analysis) will be easier to maintain and debug. The overheads in terms of code size will be negligible

Comment: And a much better way would be to change the signal handler so that it resets volatile variable, which could be checked in `for` loop - it is always better to have clean exit from `main`.

Comment: Please tell about the program. `for a linux daemon` Which linux deamon? Is it open source? Please post a link to the source code. `is structured like this:` Please do not post "like this" code snippets - please post the actual code. Could you write __exactly__ what function is that `p_clean_exit()`? Is it `pthread_cleanup_pop()`?

Comment: @WeatherVane, r3mainer, I see how those could explain it, yes. So more of a code policy matter than an actual current functionality.

Comment: @SergeyA, that's precisely how I'd tackle a situation like this

Comment: @KamilCuk, it's the open source mailpiler mail archiving project. Source at https://bitbucket.org/jsuto/piler/src/master/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does this make actual sense under **some** circumstance?

Yes, there are function macros in C and there is Duff's `case` machine and `setjmp` function call in C. There may be a call to `setjmp` above that executes a `switch` and "jumps over" the endless loop to execute cleanup code, when a `longjmp` is executed from some code running concurrently to the main thread.

```
#define p_clean_init(context)   switch (setjmp(context)) { case 0:
#define p_clean_exit()          case 1: }

jmp_buf context;
int signal_handler(...) {
    siglongjmp(context, 1);
}   
int main() {
    signal(..., signal_handler);
    p_clean_init(context);

    for(;;){ sleep(1); }

    p_clean_exit();
}
```

There are [`pthread_cleanup_push` and `pthread_cleanup_pop` functions](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_cleanup_push.3.html) that are used in a similar fashion - and from documentation we know that `POSIX.1  permits  pthread_cleanup_push() and pthread_cleanup_pop() to be implemented as macros that expand to text containing '{' and '}'`. You may explore it's [glibc implementation](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/sysdeps/nptl/pthread.h.html#_M/pthread_cleanup_push).

Maybe worth noting: by expanding macros to a `switch(...)` (but also to `goto` with labels as values GCC extension) is explored by [pthreadthread project](https://github.com/Akagi201/protothreads/tree/master/include), the method used most notably by Contiki OS. But it would not work here unless the endless loop would yield periodically.

Comment: Oh, yes! I forgot you could accomplish nearly anything by abusing the preprocessor. Also forgot about the duff's device. That as a wild ride when I learnt about it a few years back.
I'd never get involved with any of these techniques on my own volition. Anyway I'm accepting your answer as I saw what you did emphasizing the word "some" in my question :-)

Answer (score 2):

> Does this make actual sense under some circumstance?

None of the code in your example really makes much sense: there's no point in writing a daemon that wakes up once per second only to sleep again without doing anything. But it's okay, because this is just a sample... it's the skeleton of a daemon, and it's understood that you'll add code inside that loop that does something interesting. The code that you add might call `break` or otherwise cause the loop to exit, and that's when it's good form to call `p_clean_exit()`.

So **yes**, it's true that if you were to compile and run the code as is, the call to `p_clean_exit()` won't mean much. But **no**, it's not pointless to have it there, because the whole point of the code isn't to use it as is, it's to show you how to structure a real daemon, and a real daemon should absolutely clean up after itself.

Comment: Thanks for your input @Caleb. The question springs from examining code for a real open source project. The intent is to present only what I cannot fathom in its structure.
There's no loop involved. This main function binds to a network port ans launches some worker subprocesses which service requests to said port.  Termination is handled by signal handlers alse set up here. This infinite loop just prevents the process from terminating.